# Docker mysql container does not allow remote connection

Tags: mysql, docker

I have an error `Access denied for user 'bonus_user'@'my-ip' (using password: YES)` when trying to connect from my mysql client to dockerized mysql server on remote machine

My docker-compose file:

```
bonus_db:
 container_name: bonus_db
 image: mysql:5.7
 command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
 restart: unless-stopped
 ports:
   - "3306:3306"
 environment:
   MYSQL_USER: bonus_user
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: bonus_pass
   MYSQL_DATABASE: bonus_db
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_pass
volumes:
  - /var/lib/volumes/bonusdata:/var/lib/mysql
```

Here's also log of container starting:

```
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14 15:06:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14 15:06:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14 15:06:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.470897Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.480712Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.31) starting as process 1 ...
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.502124Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.504807Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.504851Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.504878Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.504894Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.504906Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.505684Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.506021Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.522229Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.548073Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.554315Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.568903Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.603166Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.605892Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.654737Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.656736Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.656771Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.657961Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.708340Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.31 started; log sequence number 13750567
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.709023Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.711205Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.715836Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201114 15:06:06
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.721862Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.721918Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.723943Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.724051Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.725417Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.725502Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.725525Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.725562Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.740164Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.765251Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
bonus_db    | 2020-11-14T15:06:06.765978Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
bonus_db    | Version: '5.7.31'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I tried to log in into container on remote machine like this:

```
docker exec -i bonus_db mysql -ubonus_user -pbonus_pass
```

And it seems working, because if I pass wrong password here, it will give the same error `Access denied`. I've also tried to import data from sql file

```
docker exec -i bonus_db mysql -ubonus_user -pbonus_pass bonus_db < dump.sql
```

and it also seems working, it's processing a couple of seconds and then exits to the terminal. But I cant access database from my local machine and from other containers too.

Comment: Well, did you `GRANT` any users external access?

Comment: How are you trying to connect to it?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am trying to connect via DBeaver, getting error `Access denied for user 'bonus_user'@'my-ip' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Please edit the question to add these details.  Make sure to include the settings that you're using to try to connect (hostname, port, username) and clarify whether the client is running in Docker, on the same host, or somewhere else.

Comment: @DavidMaze I will not write my real server IP here, credentails are correct, because I can log in to mysql within container. DBeaver is running on my local machine, and also there's PHP application running within the same docker-compose instance, and it also cant connect to MySQL

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think it is already granted, here is output for `SHOW GRANTS FOR bonus_user;` :

`GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'bonus_user'@'%'`